# Calling function library scala

Tags: scala

I'm looking to call the ATR function from this scala wrapper for ta-lib. But I can't figure out how to use wrapper correctly.

```
package io.github.patceev.talib

import com.tictactec.ta.lib.{Core, MInteger, RetCode}

import scala.concurrent.Future

object Volatility {
    def ATR(
        highs: Vector[Double],
        lows: Vector[Double],
        closes: Vector[Double],
        period: Int = 14
    )(implicit core: Core): Future[Vector[Double]] = {
        val arrSize = highs.length - period + 1

        if (arrSize < 0) {
            Future.successful(Vector.empty[Double])
        } else {
            val begin = new MInteger()
            val length = new MInteger()
            val result = Array.ofDim[Double](arrSize)

            core.atr(
                0, highs.length - 1, highs.toArray, lows.toArray, closes.toArray,
                period, begin, length, result
            ) match {
                case RetCode.Success =>
                    Future.successful(result.toVector)
                case error =>
                    Future.failed(new Exception(error.toString))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would someone be able to explain how to use function and print out the result to the console.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error that you are seeing? Does it complain about a missing implicit?

Comment: @stefanobaghino Yes, exactly

Comment: @stefanobaghino To be precise. `code` Error:(40, 6) could not find implicit value for parameter core: com.tictactec.ta.lib.Core
  ATR(highs,lows,closes,14) `code` Error:(40, 6) not enough arguments for method ATR: (implicit core: com.tictactec.ta.lib.Core)scala.concurrent.Future[Vector[Double]].
Unspecified value parameter core.
  ATR(highs,lows,closes,14)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding syntax, Scala is one of many languages where you call functions and methods passing arguments in parentheses (mostly, but let's keep it simple for now):

```
def myFunction(a: Int): Int = a + 1

myFunction(1) // myFunction is called and returns 2
```

On top of this, Scala allows to specify multiple parameters lists, as in the following example:

```
def myCurriedFunction(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b

myCurriedFunction(2)(3) // myCurriedFunction returns 5
```

You can also *partially apply* `myCurriedFunction`, but again, let's keep it simple for the time being. The main idea is that you can have multiple lists of arguments passed to a function.

Built on top of this, Scala allows to define a list of *implicit* parameters, which the compiler will automatically retrieve for you based on some scoping rules. Implicit parameters are used, for example, by `Future`s:

```
// this defines how and where callbacks are run
// the compiler will automatically "inject" them for you where needed
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

Future(4).map(_ + 1) // this will eventually result in a Future(5)
```

Note that both `Future` and `map` have a second parameter list that allows to specify an implicit execution context. By having one in scope, the compiler will "inject" it for you at the call site, without having to write it explicitly. You could have still done it and the result would have been

```
Future(4)(ec).map(_ + 1)(ec)
```

That said, I don't know the specifics of the library you are using, but the idea is that you have to instantiate a value of type `Core` and either bind it to an `implicit val` or pass it explicitly.

The resulting code will be something like the following

```
val highs: Vector[Double] = ???
val lows: Vector[Double] = ???
val closes: Vector[Double] = ???
implicit val core: Core = ??? // instantiate core
val resultsFuture = Volatility.ATR(highs, lows, closes) // core is passed implicitly
for (results <- resultsFuture; result <- results) {
  println(result)
}
```

Note that depending on your situation you may have to also use an implicit `ExecutionContext` to run this code (because you are extracting the `Vector[Double]` from a `Future`). Choosing the right execution context is another kind of issue but *to play around* you may want to use the global execution context.

---

#### Extra

Regarding some of the points I've left open, here are some pointers that hopefully will turn out to be useful:

- [Operators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html)
- [Multiple Parameter Lists (Currying)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html)
- [Implicit Parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html)
- [Scala Futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/futures.html)

Comment: Thank you, I still have trouble calling the functions, I have tried your solution but I can't even get the code to compile. Here is the library in question: https://github.com/patceev/ta-lib-scala. Maybe I should have posted the full wrapper code from the beginning.